# Contar quantas vezes um valor aparece em uma Coluna PHP e SQL

Tags: php

Gostaria de que o código automaticamente contasse e mostrasse ao lado das opções do formulário, a quantidade de vezes que os valores que são puxados do banco de dados aparecem na TABELA clients COLUNA conta

obs: Os valores das opções são puxadas da TABELA accounts COLUNA usuario,
e queria que os valores puxados que estão nas opções fossem contados na TABELA clients COLUNA conta

queria deixar assim igual na imagem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xceBC.png

já esse último valor não está na cadastrado na tabela accounts coluna usuario então por isso ele não precisa aparecer nas opções e nem ser contado.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB6Jh.png

SELECT conta, COUNT(*)
FROM clients
GROUP BY conta

```
<div class="form-group">
      <text class="bold">
        Conta *
        </text><br>
        <select name="conta" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="">Selecione a conta</option>
            <?php 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                {
                echo "<option value='".$row['usuario']."'>".$row['usuario']."</option>";
                }
}
?>  
        </select>
</div>
```

e se possivel se contar e der 6 ou mais, desabilitar a opção (disabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dê um alias a contagem:

```
SELECT conta, COUNT(0) total FROM clients GROUP BY conta
```

No `while` verifique se o total é maior que 5, e defina o `disabled`, e o resto é concatenar:

```
<?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    # verifica se é maior que 5 e seta disabled
    $disable = ($row['total'] > 5) ? 'disabled' : '';
    # gera linha
    echo '<option value="' . $row['conta'] . '" ' . $disable . '>' . $row['conta'] . '(' . $row['total']  . ')</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: perfeito! muito obrigado por ter ajudado! :)

Comment: na verdade esse alias que você falou onde eu coloco ele?
pois eu apenas troquei a variável $sqldata = "SELECT * FROM accounts"; pra o que você disse $data = "SELECT conta, COUNT(0) total FROM clients GROUP BY conta"; e invez de puxar as contas da tabela accounts puxou as contas da tabela clients.

Comment: Você não queria contar a quantidade de contas da tabela `clients`? Que foi o select que passou `SELECT conta, COUNT(*) FROM clients GROUP BY conta`. Se for da `accounts` (se eu entendi direito, seria `SELECT usuario, COUNT(*) FROM accounts GROUP BY usuario`. Ou você quer puxar valores da `accounts` e contar da `clients`? Qual a ligação entre as 2 tabelas?

Comment: é que na tabela ACCOUNTS eu cadastro as contas, e na tabela CLIENTS eu cadastro os clientes, e na hora que eu vou cadastrar os clientes eu puxo as contas que estão disponíveis da tabela ACCOUNTS, e eu posso cadastrar até 6 cliente pra cada conta, é basicamente um compartilhamento de contas, por isso que na hora que eu to cadastrando o cliente queria já ver pela opções quantos estão usando aquela conta, entende?

Comment: Agora entendi, então tem que fazer um `JOIN`. E não tem motivo algum você trazer as contas com mais de 5, já que vai deixar disabled, trás somente as que ainda tem "espaço". Não vou conseguir fazer isso agora, talvez um pouco mais tarde, ou amanhã, e atualizo a resposta pra você.

Comment: Como está a relação de contas x clientes? Porque esse campo "usuario" na "accounts" tá estranho, já que você vincula mais de um usuário em uma conta, certo!?

Comment: realmente a tabela ACCOUNTS tem um campo usuario, e a tabela CLIENTS tem um campo conta, mas fica armazenado os mesmo dados, só que apenas ta com um nome diferente.
os valores armazenados da coluna USUARIO tabela ACCOUNTS vão para coluna CONTA da tabela CLIENTS.
eu acho que eu só coloquei assim na hora, pra mim não confundir com o nome da pessoa, por isso não coloquei usuário coloquei conta.

Comment: Tenta assim: `SELECT c.codigoconta, (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM accounts WHERE conta = c.id) total FROM clients c` . onde está `codigoconta`, é o campo da conta que deve exibir, que deve ser `id` provavelmente. Aí vc tem que trocar no `$row['conta']` para o nome da coluna correto.

Comment: Tem muita definição errada, o correto é reestruturar esse bd primeiro, entender porque, depois entender o select, depois o while.

Comment: não entendi esse último código que você passou, eu troquei ```codigoconta``` por ```conta``` mas veio normal sem contar e veio (0).